# why getIntExtra() is always default value

Tags: java, android, android-activity, default

**at first my declaration is:**

```js
     public static final String EXTRA_TEXT="com.example.application.example.EXTRA_TEXT";
    public static final String EXTRA_NUMBER="com.example.application.example.EXTRA_NUMBER";
```

my MainActivity get number and text:

```js
        public void openActivity2(){
            EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
            String text = editText1.getText().toString();
            EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
            String number = (editText2.getText().toString());

          
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, text);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NUMBER, number);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

my Activity2 should get the number and text:

```js
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .......
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String text = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_TEXT);
        int num=intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NUMBER,0);
```

The text is well received,
but the number value is always 0.

Answer (score 0):

At `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NUMBER, number);` line, you put a String not a int format, so getIntExtra return default, try `intent.getStringExtra(key)` or `intent.getExtras().get(key)` .